# "There is an error! The root folder not exist" in tinymce filemanager

Tags: php, tinymce-4, file-manager

I have uploaded **tinymce**  4 at my domain successfully and tinymce editor is working properly but in filemanager it is giving  a error:

> There is an error! The root folder not exist.

I set up my file path in the `config.php` is like this:

```
$base_url="http://37.221.168.163/~host10ma"; //url base of site if you want only relative url leave empty
$upload_dir = '/tinymce/source/'; // path from base_url to upload base dir
$current_path = '../../source/'; // relative path from filemanager folder to upload files folder
```

But still i am getting this error, i have tried all possible solutions available on net please someone solve this.

Comment: Did you try to come up with a solution yourself? Instead of just hunting around the "net" for a ready-made fix?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because OP lied about searching all the solutions on the net.

Comment: @Griwes maybe OP has a quantum computer stashed somewhere on a colocation site

Comment: Yes i tried by myself , i am trying this since last two days and when i did not come to a correct solution then i asked this its ok if you dont know the answer i'll find myself.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used TinyMCE for a long time but looking at the documentation it looks like you are not using the right parameters in your **config.php**

http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration

Also check the installation process:

[http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/mcimagemanager:installation](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/mcimagemanager%3ainstallation)

Answer (score 0):

I added the folder name of my app to the root like this : 
$root = $root . "/myapp/";

And then left the base url empty like this :
$base_url = "";

Answer (score 0):

This thread is a bit old but I just found the solution so maybe it could help the next person with the same problem.

The `$base_url` needs to be a root URL, not a path to a specific folder. Instead of what you did, change it like this:

```
$base_url = 'http://37.221.168.163'; //url base of site if you want only relative url leave empty
$upload_dir = '/~host10ma/tinymce/source/'; // path from base_url to upload base dir
$current_path = '../../source/'; // relative path from filemanager folder to upload files folder
```

I don't know what you folder tree looks like but make sure `$current_path` is properly set. If not, nothing will happen when you try to upload a file (only preview, no actual upload). Don't forget the script is called from within the `filemanager` folder, so mind the actual number of levels you need to go back from.

Answer (score 0):

1.Assume your tinymce folder located in http://localhost/projectname/tinymce/

2.Create folder images under tinymce eg: tinymce/images

3.Go to the folder location tinymce/plugins/filemanager/config.php

4.Go to the line near 15 to 20

base_url="http://localhost/projectname/";

$upload_dir = 'tinymce/images/';

$current_path = '../../images/';

5.Add this line

**$root='/tinymce/';**

Save and Run the project.

Answer (score 0):

1. Assume your tinymce folder located in http://localhost/projectname/tinymce/
2. Create folder images under tinymce eg: tinymce/images
3. Go to the folder location tinymce/plugins/filemanager/config.php
4. Go to the line near 15 to 20-- it will be look like this

```
base_url="http://localhost/projectname/";
$upload_dir = 'tinymce/images/';
$current_path = '../../images/';
```

5. Add this line: `$root='/tinymce/'; or $root='../tinymce/';`

Save and Run the project.

Hope it works....